# scrollTo and .is(:animated) found wanting

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to have a list of textareas, dynamically created and destroyed, that when I click one it will expand, contracting the previously focused textarea if there was one, and then center itself inside its parent div.

I have the expand and contract bit.

I am having trouble centering it in the field of view.

I have a div that centers in the window, stretching from top to bottom and allowing overflow.

```
______________
| w |    | w  |
|   | d  |    |
|   |    |    |
_______________
```

How do I center that focused, now expanded, textarea in its div?

this is just a build of the gui torn down to just the relevant bits... so it's awfully crufty

[jsfiddle.net/CPEFk/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/CPEFk/1/)

.
.
.
I will say scrollTo is proving useless either to me or in my fumbling mitts... the problem I with this specifically I feel is two fold:
first, 
 sometimes the content of the div only allow a certain threshold of scrolling which can be insufficient to achieve the centered position,

second,
 that the value it is scrolling to changes from its initial calling after the two boxes contract and expand.  .is(':animated') also granting little aide in that regard.  I believe these two functions, so prevalent in solution research are useless to me, and would appreciate any design engineering advice, but if you can help me even by using these that would also be appreciated.

The headaches these builtin 'solutions' were giving me led me to a thought about some css manipulation wherein I set the absolute position as centered and then go through each textarea and set each of their positions to some distance from the centered element.  i.e. if the third box is focused, it is absolute center, then box 1 is repositioned above box 2 above 3 and then four five and six and so on are positioned in order as well.

Is this a lot of work to request of the client?

Is that what jQuery's animate() does?  DOMwide affected css manipulation...?

Comment: can you setup an example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: of scrollTo failing to work? or of .is(':animated') with scrollTo failing to work?

Comment: of your scenario, try replicating it in a fiddle, will be easier for us to understand/debug.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/CPEFk/1/

Answer (score 1):

So,

Firstly, make your `$("#foryou").animate()`  a callback function, secondly,

> `$('#foryou').top` <--undefined

So it needs to be changes to,

`$("#foryou").position().top`

The changes,

```
$(document).on('focus', '#foryou textarea', function () {
//$(this).animate({ height: boxheight }, 0);
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.animate({
        height: boxheight
    }, 1000, function () {
        $('#foryou').animate({
            scrollTop: ($this.position().top) + "px"
        });
    });
    ....
});
```

Reset the `scrollTop` of `#foryou` on every `.blur()` call.

```
$('#foryou').animate({
     scrollTop: "0px"
});
```

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/CPEFk/4/)

Comment: Still performs poorly... I stated the goal was to center the element, I understand the fiddle only scrolls to the top, or attempts to, but I did this because I felt it would be quicker to find the solution, then I could alter the solution.  That being said, the scrollTop fails to scoll to the Top of the textarea, even in your edit.  If you click a textarea, sometimes it scrolls to the top, other times it scrolls to some seemingly random area.

Comment: is your code hosted somewhere? some `url` where I can see this, jsfiddle is not very debug friendly

Comment: This is pure development.  It lacks a host, but if you have a copy of jquery you can mkdir and place the html, css, and js into files and open in your browser.  Like I said, it is only a GUI implementation so it is vacant of any server, read:system; calls.

Comment: Good work, much more consistent.  What did you change? One caveat, the problem that persists is when the scroll limit is less than necessary to scroll the textarea to the top of the div.  A hacky solution would be to pad the div signifigantly, or in some ratio of the window size...

Comment: The challenge is to keep the textarea animations and the container animations mutually exclusive. I'm resetting the `foryou` scrolltop everytime before I scroll. And yes, you'll need some kind of excessive padding for that.